# How to insert data to ArangoDB with HTTP?

Tags: arangodb

Could you help me to understand how to insert data in existing collection. Collection name is cars. I am trying to insert new data to it. I am doing like:

```
curl -X PUT --data-binary @- --dump - http://localhost:8529/_db/testdb/_api/collection/cars/ '{name: "carname"}'
```

But after it nothing happens. Look like I miss syntax.

Am I right understand that I should use `/_api/cursor` only when I am doing get request to DB like

```
{"query": "FOR car IN cars RETURN car"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `@-` in the command `curl --data-binary @- ...` you're asking curl to read from stdin. That means the command will not do anything and not complete until you press CTRL-D. However, if you press CTRL-D, it will send the data to the server.

It is possible to specify the data to send without reading it from stdin. That can be done via `curl --data-binary <data>`, with `<data>` being the JSON to send. Note that it needs to be valid JSON and correctly escaped in the shell you use. `'{name: "carname"}'` from the above example is no correct JSON (the quotes around attribute name `name` are missing). It should rather be `'{"name": "carname"}'`.

As @yojimbo87 pointed out, insert operations should be sent via HTTP POST rather than PUT, and the collection name should be passed as a URL parameter.

Here is the full command:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary '{"name": "carname"}' --dump - "http://localhost:8529/_db/testdb/_api/document?collection=cars"
```

The above will work in Bash, however, it won't work from the Windows command-line because strings there shouldn't be enclosed in `'`, but rather `"`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to insert new data into existing collection then you have to use POST verb, for example like this:

```
curl -X POST -d "{ \"field\": \"value\" }" --dump - http://localhost:8529/_db/myDatabase/_api/document?collection=cars
```

PUT verb is used for replacement of existing documents. More examples can be found in docs under [Working with Documents using REST](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpDocument/WorkingWithDocuments.html).

[Cursors](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpAqlQueryCursor/index.html) are used for executing AQL queries through REST API and they use [POST, PUT and DELETE verbs](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpAqlQueryCursor/AccessingCursors.html).